# Custom Attribute Search using SearchCriteria

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, search-criteria

I have created some custom attribute like **city** and I need to search how many products I have in a specific city using SearchCriteria.

The SearchCriteria I apply does not filter products on my city attribute and I always get all the products.

This is my code for getting a specific city Products:

```
   $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $filter_1 = $objectManager
        ->create('Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder')
        ->setField('city')
        ->setConditionType('like')
        ->setValue("Chennai%")
        ->create();
    $search_criteria =$objectManager
        ->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder')
        ->setFilterGroups([$filter_group])
        ->create();

    $repo =$objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $result = $repo->getList($search_criteria);
    $products = $result->getItems();
    echo count($products);
```

I can get all the products using the below filter:

```
   $filter_1 = $objectManager
    ->create('Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder')
    ->setField('city')
    ->setConditionType('like')
    ->setValue("%")
    ->create();
```

Can you suggest me how to get products filtering on a specific attribute?

Comment: Where does `$filter_group` come from?